# Конструктор по умолчанию для типа T (шаблоны классов)

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, шаблоны-с++

Есть реализация vector, не из пространства std, но примерно похожего по функциональности. 
Вот некоторые выдержки серверной части и клиентской.

**Файл Vect.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "VectError.h"

template<typename T>class Vect {
public:
    explicit Vect() :first(0), last(0) {}
    explicit Vect(size_t _n, const T& _v = T()) {//интересующая часть, как 
                                         //работает конструктор T(), откуда он??
        Allocate(_n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _n; ++i)
            *(first + i) = _v;
    }
    Vect(const Vect&);
    Vect& operator=(const Vect&);
    ~Vect()
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        cout << "Destructor of " << markName << endl;
#endif // DEBUG
        Destroy();
        first = 0, last = 0;
    }
    void mark(std::string& name) { markName = name; }
    std::string mark()const { return markName; }
    size_t size()const;
    T* begin()const { return first; }
    T* end()const { return last; }

    T& operator[](size_t i);
    void insert(T* _P, const T& _x);
    void push_back(const T& _x);
    void pop_back();
    void show()const;
protected:
    void Allocate(size_t _n) {
        first = new T[_n * sizeof(T)];
        last = first + _n;
    }
    void Destroy() {
        for (T* p = first; p != last; ++p)p->~T();
        delete[] first;
    }
    T* first;
    T* last;
    std::string markName;
};
```

**Выдержки из main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Vect.h"
#include <string>
...
int main()
{
  try
  { 
    Vect<int> v1(10);// вызывается конструктор 
                     //explicit Vect(size_t _n, const T& _v = T())...
    v1.mark(string ("v1"));
    size_t n = v1.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)v1[i] = i + 1;
    v1.show();
  ....
}
```

Не понятно почему в `Vect<int> v1(10)` `_v` в выражении`const T& _v = T()` по умолчанию приравнивается нулю, (откуда?) и почему можно игнорировать вообще полное заполнение, ведь по моему здесь нет соответствующей перегрузки конструктора. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данный конструктор

```
explicit Vect(size_t _n, const T& _v = T()) {//интересующая часть, как 
                                     //работает конструктор T(), откуда он??
    Allocate(_n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _n; ++i)
        *(first + i) = _v;
}
```

имеет аргумент по умолчанию для второго параметра, который равен значению выражения `T()`. Поэтому вы можете вызывать этот конструктор, не указывая второй аргумент для конструктора, как в вашем примере

```
Vect<int> v1(10);
```

В качестве второго аргумента будет использоваться это значение по умолчанию, которое присутствует в объявлении конструктора.

Выражение `T()` имеет название инициализация значением. Для фундаментальных типов такая инициализация соответствует инициализации объекта нулем.

Из стандарта C++ (8.5 Initializers)

> 10 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   (), shall be **value-initialized**

И далее

> 7 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> ...
>   — otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.

И, наконец,

> 5 To **zero-initialize** an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0
>   (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T;

Рассмотрите следующий простой пример.

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int x = 10, int y = int())
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f();
    f(1);
    f(1, 2);
}
```

Вывод этой программы на консоль будет выглядеть так

```
x = 10, y = 0
x = 1, y = 0
x = 1, y = 2
```